# Convert column data types when importing data from Excel to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

So , I want to import a data from an Eexcel file, but I have a problem I have a column in excel  that contains numerical and varchar values

For example in a column named chassisnumber I have a values with 012345 and also HAFBK123
I think the import wizard has prioritize the numeric when determining which data type should be imported.

I tried to do this but this only ignores the value that has a character and turns it into a null value

[image: I tried to do this but this only ignores the value that has a character and turns it into a null value]

[image]

This is my data from the file

[image]

Comment: So how are you importing from an Excel worksheet? (Any actual code?) A lot of Excel drivers use "type guessing" to infer the data types of each column on a worksheet by looking at the values in the first `N` rows, where `N` is configurable and often a parameter in the connection string.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning no code, just following the import wizard from SSMS.